# What's the best workflow for shooting stationary objects in a makeshift studio?

Tags: exposure, workflow, studio-lighting

I have bought the following kit to shoot my portfolio which consists of mostly books and posters:

- Super White Background + 2 strobes 100 watts each with softboxes

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1td_ZiB2yOnsX7xYhFj_sa0Vyw-0SF4CmtLeE5cvUvWk/edit?usp=sharing

I've done this kind of photography before but was never really systematic about it.

I'm wondering if someone has some thoughts on what would be the best exposures for getting the best contrast with the least amount of photoshop work.

Will be shooting with a Nikon D5000 on a tripod.

Comment: What do you mean "workflow"? Typically the term is used here to describe the ingestion of images, organization, storage, post production, and delivery to client. You seem to be wondering what settings to use on the camera?  Maybe you should start with the Studio-Setup tag here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/studio-setup otherwise - nothing is going to beat experience and trying it out. There is no magical setting.

Answer (score 1):

Use the histogram and test shots.  That shows the contrast, from the horse's mouth.  You might also test each strobe separately to see the effect on the image, to tune the effect you want as well as simply making sure everything is captured in the exposure.

Use full manual mode on the camera, for repeatable results.

Shoot a test target as well as your material.  If you really want to get picky you can shoot a gray wedge target and then examine the result in Lightroom/Photoshop rather than in-camera.